# How can i solve migration in Laravel database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

i have created a table from command

```
php artisan make:migration create_info_table --create=info
```

then i delete it for a cause from migration folder , now when i again wanted to create the table , the command console showing

```
     [ErrorException]
 include(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\composer/../../database/migrat
 016_09_01_082120_create_info_table.php): failed to open stream: No su
 e or directory
```

how can i solve this,

Answer (score 1):

in laravel for a table must create a model and best way is:

```
php artisan make:model Info -m
```

Comment: yes thanx @mohammad, i have tried this ,this command creates a model as well as migration

Answer (score 0):

Try running composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

have you deleted the migration file?

I have met the similar problem, i solved by delete the migration file and rebuild it again using the command line, and then try to migrate, it works.